# What's the difference between `apt-cache` and `apt list`?

Tags: apt, package-management

What's the difference between `apt-cache` and `apt list`? It seems that `apt list` uses installed command. I can see some packages are available in the results of `apt-cache` but they are not seen in the  results of `apt list` .

1. `apt-cache policy graphviz`

```
graphviz:
  Installed: 2.42.2-6
  Candidate: 2.42.2-6
  Version table:
 *** 2.42.2-6 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

2. `apt list --installed | grep graphviz`

```
None
```

So what exactly is the difference between the two commands? Does it mean that even though one candidate (package version) is available for installation none is installed?

Comment: Note the line in `apt-cache policy`: `Installed: (none)`

Comment: `apt-cache policy` tells you that **if** you decided to install or upgrade that package, which versions you have available to choose from and their sources. For example, that you have --in this case-- a single choice:  You would get version  2.36.0-0ubuntu3.1 from trusty-security.

Comment: `apt policy` is super useful for looking into problems with the package system because it shows you all available versions, where they came from, and what you have installed.  `apt list` shows what you have installed.

Answer (score 2):

`apt-get list --installed | grep graphviz` reports whether the graphviz package is installed or not. The same information as `apt-get list --installed | grep graphviz` reports is also reported by this shorter command.

```
apt list --installed graphviz
```

`apt-cache policy graphviz` reports if graphviz is installed and also lists the graphviz package's available installation candidates and their sources. The same information as `apt-cache policy graphviz` reports is also reported by this shorter command.

```
apt policy graphviz
```

apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use apt with caution in scripts. Try replacing `apt list --installed | grep graphviz` with `apt-get list --installed | grep graphviz` and check if the results are less different than they were in the original two commands.